# Proper way to achieve prototypal inheritance

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

I'd like to establish an inheritance relation between some *classes*. Take, for instance, `Element` which would be the *abstract superclass*, and then `Rect` and `Triangle` as *child classes*.

`Element` has some common code in its constructor, besides the common functions set on its prototype.

```
Element = function (id, attr) {
    // Setting attributes and id...
    this._callback_click = _bind(this._callback_click, this);
};
```

---

I've been reading some questions, [such as this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985460/proper-javascript-inheritance), and it seems there's more than one way to go about it, although they *might* be equivalent in the end.

1. Using `new`:

   ```
   Rect = function (id, attr) {
       Element.call(this, id, attr);
       // Setting Rect's own attributes...
   };

   Rect.prototype = new Element(null, {});
   Rect.prototype.constructor = Rect;
   // Seems somewhat pointless to pass these arguments, but I have none
   // at this point in the code.
   ```
2. Using `Object.create`:

   ```
   Rect = function (id, attr) {
       Element.call(this, id, attr);
       // Setting Rect's own attributes...
   };

   Rect.prototype = Object.create(Element.prototype);
   Rect.prototype.constructor = Rect;
   ```
3. Using *temporary constructors*:

   ```
   function makePrototype(superclass) {
       function f() { }
       f.prototype = superclass.prototype;
       f.prototype.constructor = f;
       return new f();
   }

   Rect = function (id, attr) {
       Element.call(this, id, attr);
       // Setting Rect's own attributes...
   };

   Rect.prototype = makePrototype(Element);
   Rect.prototype.constructor = Rect;
   ```
4. Using `clone`:

   ```
   function clone(object) {
       var key, copy = {};
       for (key in object) { copy[key] = object[key]; }
       return copy;
   }

   Rect = function (id, attr) {
       Element.call(this, id, attr);
       // Setting Rect's own attributes...
   };

   Rect.prototype = clone(Element.prototype);
   Rect.prototype.constructor = Rect;
   ```

---

**Does any of these methods have an (dis)advantage over the others?**

I suspect the `clone` method might not be *correct*, although I'm not sure as to what the reason could be.

Finally, correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe the `new` method could show unexpected results, since `_callback_click` is bound twice (when setting the prototype, and when calling the `Element` constructor from within `Rect`).

Comment: you can see coffeescript way, [coffeescript inheritance](http://coffeescript.org/#try:class%20Element%0A%20%20constructor%3A%20-%3E%20console.log%20'amazing'%0A%0Aclass%20Rect%20extends%20Element%0A%20%20initialize%3A%20-%3E%20console.log%20'way')

Comment: @IdanWender Interesting. At a first glance, it seems like an improved mix of some of the methods above.

Comment: http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/ is also a good read.

Comment: @KerryLiu A good read, indeed. Reminds me of Backbone.js's way of doing it.

Comment: Also, [Object.Create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) is the [ES5](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/) way of doing prototypical inheritance.